# Creating a method checking for i in an array (only returns false)

Tags: java

So, I´ve got this task that I just can't master. I know that the answer must be trivial, but I just can´t figure it out, and its so frustrating!

Task: Create a method **static boolean find(int[] a)**, which should return true if the the field a[i] contains values in any position that is equal to i. If not, the method should return false. The field does not contain any doublicates.

This is how far I´ve come (right now the method only outputs "false"):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] array = {1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 99, 11, 23};

    boolean answer;

    answer = find(array);

    System.out.print(answer);

}
static boolean find(int[] a) { 
    int i = 7; //Obviously, this is not the way of doing it...
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++); {
        if (i == a[i]) {
        return true;
        }
    }
    return false;      
}
}
```

Thus, I am clearly thinking wrong, but how?

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: *Mastering* this requires no more than a brief inspection of your code to see the problem.  I'd step through it with a debugger (Eclipse or other IDEs can help you with this) if the problem isn't apparent at glace.  Would help you understand and solve such issues going forward without aid.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
if (i == a[i])
```

to:

```
if (j == a[j])
```

Otherwise, looping through the array doesn't make much sense, as always one and the same check is applied.

This wouldn't have happened if you named your variables more carefully. :)

Comment: I think the intention is probably `i == a[j]`, but agree with respect to your prognosis of the problem and recommended future actions.  +1 for recommending how to prevent them from shooting themselves in the foot in the future.

Comment: As an addendum, I didn't read their task.  After reading, I agree with your change.

Answer (score 1):

in for loop change if condition put j in place of i and see

```
if (i == a[j])
```

this simply gives output you are expecting

For logic to be correct if condition will be

```
if (j==a[j])
```

Comment: "For logic to be correct if condition will be `if (j==a[j])`" Don't think this is true; that says "if index is equal to value at the index...".  The correct logic is likely suppose to be "if value at the index is equal to the value I'm searching for...", which would be `if (i == a[j])` (your first correction).

Comment: As an addendum, I didn't read their task.  After reading, I agree with your statement about correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

Change the condition inside the loop from

```
if(i==a[i])
```

to

```
if(i==a[j])
```

Your original condition mixed the desired value (i) with the cell index (j).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having a single answer that corrects the problems (which the asker has resolved, through a combination of the answers posted here, and the comments of a now-removed answer):

1) As mentioned by others, and based on what is outlined in the task, the logic needs to be changed:

```
if (j == a[j]) {
```

2) The loops is terminated with a semi-colon; the block is **not** run within the loop (it is run after the loop finishes fruitlessly incrementing `j`).  To fix, remove the semi-colon:

```
for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) { // No ';' after ')'
```

In addition (but not directly related to the problem), remove the `i` field; as was rightly concluded in the code comment, it does not need to be there once these two issues are fixed.